# Is the cardinality of a topology always of the form $2^n$?

Tags: general-topology

**Just to recap:** Let $M$ be any set. A set $\mathcal{O}_M \subseteq P(M)$ is a topology on $M$ if it satisfies the three things that it satisfies (I won't write them down since it's not relevant to my question).

---

My question is directed toward the fact that $\mathcal{O}_M \subseteq P(M)$.

We know that for any set $M, |P(M)| = 2^{|M|}.$

Does this imply that all topologies always have a cardinality of $2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Did you check some topologies on small spaces, for example spaces with only two or three points?

Comment: No, I just got into the material recently so I’m just making connections

Comment: Cf. [Sierpinski space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpiński_space)

Comment: It's a good exercise to enumerate all topologies with at most three points—several of these are useful to keep in mind as possible counterexamples to check conjectures against.

Comment: A topology on a space with $n$ elements has cardinality *at most* $2^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Consider the topology $\{\emptyset,M,\{x\}\}$ for $x\in M\ne\{x\}$.

Comment: Oh that’s brilliant. I didn’t even think about that. Excellent counterexample

Comment: You can also consider $\{\emptyset,M,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ where $a,b\in M$ which has more than two elements.

Comment: Well, $3=2^n$ for $n=\log_2 3$. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $X =\{ a,b,c \} $ and note that $ T = \{ \varnothing, X, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\} \}$ is a topology on $X$.  Moreover cardinality of $T$ is $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Since finite examples were given, let me give an infinite example. Consider the cofinite topology on $\Bbb N$. Since there are countably many finite subsets of $\Bbb N$, the cofinite topology is countable. However, there is no set $A$ such that $|2^A|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: And to clarify, you don’t mean to say: there is no set $A$ such that $2^{|A|} = \aleph_o$, right? Because $|2^A|$ is just a value. Even though technically you can’t raise a number to a set $A$

Comment: I mean to say *exactly* that.

Comment: You mean to say exactly what I said or exactly what you said?

Comment: There is no set whose power set is countably infinite.

Comment: Oh right. Because $P(\mathbb{N}) = |\mathbb{R}|$ right?

Comment: Well, also that.

Comment: Well yeah since the reals are uncountable. That’s another way of putting it

Comment: Well, the important thing is that there is also no smaller set whose power set is countably infinite, because smaller cardinals are finite, and finite sets have finite power set.